# R - create plot grid and then plot data points

Tags: r, plot, categories, scatter-plot

I was wondering if it is possible to create only the "grid" of a plot in R and then add the data points according to the values in the matrix. For instance, I would like to have on the X axis some calendar year values and on the Y axis the name of some countries. Then, depending on the data in my matrix, I would add a point in the graph where needed.
Example data:
`Y_labels = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Germany", "Spain")` and `X_labels = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995)`. Let's suppose the vector containing the data points to plot is something like `x = cbind(c(1991, 1993, 1995),c("Belgium", "Spain", "Belgium"))`. Then I would add a point/circle/whatever at Belgium - 1991. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

Just create an empty plot, with type "n" (for none)

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(1992, 1995, 1998, 1999), 
                 country = c("Austria", "Spain", "Spain", "Germany"))

# All the possible countries
all.countries <- c("Austria", "Belgium", "Germany", "Spain");
# Convert df$country to a factor
df$country <- factor(df$country, levels=all.countries)
# yaxt="n" hides the y axis, be sure to specify xlim and ylim
# so that your data fits in the graph!
plot(0, t="n", xlim=c(1990, 2000), ylim=c(1, length(all.countries)), 
     yaxt="n", xlab="Year", ylab="Country")
# Plot a y axis
axis(2, at=1:length(all.countries), labels=all.countries)
# points plots over an existing graph
points(df, pch=20)
```